# Not able to convert from HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z' to HH:MM format Java

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime, java-time, datetime-parsing

I'm trying to convert into HH:MM format in Java

Here is my code

```
String date = "18:30:00.000Z";

    try {
        ZonedDateTime parsed = ZonedDateTime.parse(date);

        ZonedDateTime z = parsed.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault());

        DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(fmt.format(z));
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Is there anything wrong in my code

Here is the exception

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '18:30:00.000Z' could not be parsed at index 0
```

Comment: Could you provide the exception/error output?

Comment: 18:30:00.000Z isn't a `ZonedDateTime` - what would you expect the date to be? The closest type would be `OffsetTime` (with an offset of 0). Is it *always* going to be Z at the end though? If so, I'd probably trim that and parse as a LocalTime, then format with a different formatter.

Comment: `ZonedDateTime` expects an ISO-8601 style String, such as `2007-12-03T10:15:30+01:00 Europe/Paris`. [source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html)

Comment: I'm expecting 18:30:00.000Z will return as 6:30PM

Comment: @JonSkeet, can you pls let me know what needs to be done, I'm expecting 18:30:00.000Z will return as 6:30PM

Comment: Why the jodatime tag? It seems inappropriate here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string you are trying to parse is not a date and time, but only a time. So the type `ZonedDateTime` is not the appropriate type to use here. Use `OffsetTime` instead, which is a class for holding just a time (without a date).

```
String input = "18:30:00.000Z";
OffsetTime time = OffsetTime.parse(input);
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h:mm a");
String result = formatter.format(time);
System.out.println(result);
```

Output:

```
6:30 PM
```

Comment: Simple and perfect. Thank you.

Comment: More precisely, as the name says, `OffsetTime` is for a time *with an offset from UTC*. The `Z` in your string means offset zero from UTC, so this is just perfect.